# AWS Cognito SignUP with custom Attributes in node js causing error

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I am trying to build Signup through a lambda function with AWS user pool where I added a custom attribute called type.
When I am sending a type value with signup, an error "**A client attempted to write unauthorized attribute**" is populating.

I am using 'amazon-cognito-identity-js' package to save data.
Here is my code snippet

```
        const attributeList = [];
        attributeList.push(new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute({Name:"name",Value:user.username}));
        attributeList.push(new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute({Name:"custom:type",Value:'asd'}));
        attributeList.push(new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute({Name:"gender",Value:user.gender}));
        attributeList.push(new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute({Name:"email",Value:user.email}));

        userPool.signUp(user.email, user.password, attributeList, null, function(err, result){
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
           return resolve(result);
        });**strong text**
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After that you added a new attribute, you should select the user attributes this app client can read and write.

Steps:

1. Go to your Cognito User Pool page
2. Click on the "App Client" from the left side menu
3. Click on the "Set attribute read and write permissions"
4. Make sure you added the necessary(read/write) permissions for the needed attribute

[image]
[image]

Comment: Also, if these are protected attributes (meaning you do not want the user to have access to change them), you may not want to give write permissions and only update them server side.

Comment: really helpful thanks you

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answer, sometimes custom attributes may take time to reflect under clients. Because I noticed it around 15 mins but after 1 hour it was there.